# Creating Volume, Attaching volume and Mouting it to EC2 instance using Ansible

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible, mount, amazon-ebs

I have created an Ansible playbook, which performs the following tasks:

1. Create an EBS volume.
2. Attach the volume to an existing EC2 instance.
3. Mount the volume in the instance.

   ```
   - name: Creating a Volume
     hosts: all
     sudo: yes
     tasks:

   - name: Creating a Volume
     ec2_vol:
       aws_access_key: "{{ lookup('env', 'AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID') }}"
       aws_secret_key: "{{ lookup('env', 'AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY') }}"
       instance: 'i-7edebfdb'
       volume_size: 5
       device_name: /dev/xvdf
       region: 'ap-northeast-1'
       volume_type: gp2
     register: ec2_vol

    - name: Printing the volume information
      debug: var=ec2_vol

    - name: mounting the volume
      mount: name=/mnt fstype=ext4 state=mounted src=/dev/xvdf
   ```

But when I executed the playbook, received the following error.

```
failed: [172.30.1.237] => {"failed": true}
msg: Error mounting /mnt: mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/xvdf,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail  or so
```

When I perfromed `fdisk -l` I can see the volume. But it is not mounted.

In `dmesg` there is can see the error message
Can't find ext4 filesystem

How to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 3):

According to your logs, The error clearly mentions there is no file system on Volume. **That means you are not formatting (Creating a filesystem) on EBS Volume.**

Please include a task to format the Volume with a supported/required filesystem type before you mount.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yeah, but `fstype` option must create a filesystem